# How can load ajax data when drop down already selected?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my editor panel. I can get data when drop down item change. But I want to load data in edit action that loading again when the data in the drop down is selected.

[image]

Comment: So you want to do it on `.click()` instead of `.change()`? Or do you mean on initial page load?

Comment: on initial page load

Comment: You can mimic a change on initial page load by just doing [`.change();`](https://api.jquery.com/change/). For example `$(function(){ $('#yourSelect').change(); });`. This will act like the select was changed, and will trigger your other function.

Comment: thanks for you quick response. already I did that when I insert data mode then it's work fine on onchange but it's not load data in edit mode when already route selected.

Comment: got it using this method:
$('.routelist').find(":selected").text();